# Subquery returned more than 1 value regardless of identity for Update statement

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am having issues using a sub-query to return a value I need for an update statement.  I am working with a CRM database here. I have used a job to import some fields, but i now need to use an update statement as not all fields are available in the importer.

When i imported the actions, I used an Actionname field as a combination of the ID fields to create an identity for each action in the event I needed to make updates to the data.

I need to update the "Subject" field using the RequestorComments field specific to each action (either 2016 Conference or 2017 Conference), but my subquery is not recognizing the combination of a `string, SecurityID (FK), ContactID (FK) and an identity` as a unique value.

I have also tried using select TOP 1 for the subquery, but this returns "2017 Conference" for each row instead.

```
DECLARE @Actions TABLE (ContactID nvarchar(256), PersonID int, CompletorComments nvarchar(256), RequestorComments nvarchar(256), SecurityListingID int, SubstatusCode int, CompletedDate datetime, Number int not null identity (1,1))
INSERT INTO @Actions VALUES ('34733','211','Corporation1','2017 Conference','2648','10014','2017-01-23 00:00:00')
INSERT INTO @Actions VALUES ('34733','211','Corporation2','2016 Conference','9103','10014','2016-01-23 00:00:00')

UPDATE dbo.Action
SET Subject = (select RequestorComments
           from @Actions a
           join dbo.action act (nolock)
           on act.name = 'TRST-1289' + cast(SecurityListingID as nvarchar) + ContactID + cast(Number as nvarchar)
           where  act.CreatedDate between '2017-07-27 15:00:09.540' and '2017-07-27 15:05:09.540')
,UpdatedBy = 9999
,UpdatedDate = getdate ()
--select *
from @Actions a
join dbo.action act (nolock)
on act.name = 'TRST-1289' + cast(SecurityListingID as nvarchar) + ContactID + 
cast(Number as nvarchar)
where  act.CreatedDate between '2017-07-27 15:00:09.540' and '2017-07-27 
15:05:09.540'
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data for the actions field? Also, the join between Actions and @Actions is pretty nasty in terms of performance. You may want to have that already concatenated as a field in the temp table for easier matching

Comment: If `act.name` has duplicates in `action` table between the passed `act.CreatedDate` you will get this error

Comment: @eli Thank you for the note re: concatenation - I will make sure to update that. The 2 insert into statements below the insert statement are 2 rows of sample data. Where Corporation1 attended the 2017 comments and that needs to feed into the Subject field. Corporation2 attended 2016 and needs that to feed into the Subject field

Comment: Thank you @Pரதீப். Would I need to remove the WHERE clause from both the subquery and the update statement itself?

Comment: @JeffRock I meant sample data for the Action table - sorry about the mistype.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use a subquery for this. You simply want to use some joins in your update statement. Something like this.

```
UPDATE act
SET Subject = a.RequestorComments
    , UpdatedBy = 9999
    , UpdatedDate = getdate ()
from @Actions a
join dbo.action act
on act.name = 'TRST-1289' + cast(SecurityListingID as nvarchar) + ContactID + cast(Number as nvarchar)
where  act.CreatedDate between '2017-07-27 15:00:09.540' and '2017-07-27 15:05:09.540'
```

You may notice I removed the NOLOCK hint. This is a bad habit to throw this hint everywhere and in an update it can really mess things up for you. http://blogs.sqlsentry.com/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere/

You also are casting to varchar but you did not specify the size, this is critical as the default size for varchar can vary depending on usage. Avoid the problem entirely by ALWAYS specifying the size.

Comment: Thank you very much @Sean Lange! That did the trick. I was running into issues pulling the field directly from the temp table and decided to try some suggestions i saw based on using a subquery. I no longer receive the error and was able to run the update. I will be sure to specify the size when casting, did not think about that.

Comment: Great glad this helped. Do you understand the logic and why you need to do this instead of the subquery approach?

Comment: I believe so - thanks for asking! I know it reduces the amount of code and is pulling the data directly from the source where the join conditions are met. Any other drawbacks of using the subquery approach here (other than it does not work :) )?

Comment: The subquery approach doesn't work because it needs to a join to get the correct value for each row. :D